# YUI 3 - Set global request headers for Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, yui

I've mostly worked with jQuery before and I'm new to YUI. I wish to set a custom header for each Ajax request using either IO or DataSource in YUI 3. I want the header to be inserted automatically for each request. In jQuery I could accomplish this with $.ajaxPrefilter like so:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    var value = 'blah';
    if (value) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("My-Custom-Header", value);
    }
});
```

I found these pages in the online documentation for YUI 3 but I just don't "get it". How can I accomplish this?

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/io/io-get.html

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/io.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the "header" method in the io module: [API docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/io.html)

I haven't tested it, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
YUI().use('io', function(Y) {
    Y.io.header('X-My-Header', 'My Custom Value');

    Y.io(/*...*/); // Should have the X-My-Header HTTP header
});
```

Note that this will only apply to the current YUI instance. So if you have another `YUI().use(/.../)` statement, you'll need to set the header again.

If you need it to provide headers across instances, you should define your own module that wraps the Y.io functionality. Check out [this gist](http://jsfiddle.net/4CUWQ/1/) to get a sense of what that entails.

Comment: Ah! This was what I was looking for. However, it's most unfortunate that it does not work across YUI instances. My application will consist of multiple YUI instances.

Comment: Awesome Nick. Above and beyond what I was expecting. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this gist but it generates an exception, complaining 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'io:0' of undefined'.

Comment: Ah there is a mistake in the gist. It should be Y.Object.each(origIo, function(v,k). Regardless, doesn't seem to work across instances though

Answer (score 3):

I honestly don't think it is good idea to do it "JQuery style". Either way you need to provide configuration object, so few more characters doesn't make much difference.

But the worst part is that when someone else will see your code he will not have idea where the additional headers come from and he will probably waste hours of his life.

If you still want to have default headers somewhere, do it Javascript way like so:

```js
Y.myDefaultIOCfg={"My-Custom-Header":value}
...
var cfg=Y.merge(Y.myDefaultIOCfg, {
    method: 'GET',
    data: 'foo=bar'
})
request = Y.io(uri, cfg)
```

This way you explicitly say that you are using some object as a pattern for the config object and additional header definition can be found there.

Comment: Agreed. jQuery's lack of structure is one of the reasons I decided to use YUI for this particular project. This technique is not too cumbersome and I was able to easily make it work. Also, it has the added benefit of leaving a trail for other developers to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know YUI syntax very well, but try this:

```
YUI().use("io-base", function(Y) {
  var cfg, request;

  cfg = {
    methos: 'GET',
    data: 'foo=bar',
    headers: {
      'My-Custom-Header': value
    }
  }

  request = Y.io(uri, cfg);
});
```

Comment: Thanks anton, but I've already been doing what you suggested. What I was hoping to do was have the header automatically inserted without having to do it each time. The YUI docs just aren't very clear on this. Or perhaps I'm a little dense! :)